# Jar to perform step by step processing

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

I just want to know whether there are any programming language to achieve a task that is descried below.

I have to develop a tool and it should perform the operations step by step based on my input.

Steps include, FTPing some files -> starting a job -> Processing the output file -> generating report.

Is there any jar written in java which can be used for this? Apart from java, my lead told to try "Ruby in Rails" and i have no idea in "Ruby in Rails". Can this be achieved using Rails?

Thanks and i don't know whether this is the correct forum to post such questions. Please redirect if inappropriate.

Comment: This could certainly be done in java (and I would be staggered if it couldn't be done in Ruby on Rails) but I think you would need to write a program to process the files as per your specifications. There isn't going to be a prebuild jar that just does it. Could you be a little more clear what you mean by "based on my input." though. Are you looking for a scripting language?

Comment: It is basically to automate the process. To run a job we need to FTP files, start the server, start the job and after the job completes we process the output and then generate report. This is one kind of process, other job or group of task can come in later for eg search a pattern in log -> if exists generate report, mail them , restart tomcat. I have to develop a webapp to get the steps that i need to process and the app should perform it.